# Cannot post javascript object with $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a javascript object so i can post it to my backend later but i am having some trouble with this.

This is my code that i am trying. When i make console.log to the object everything is fine but when i post it with `$.post` i got some errors. I think that error is comming because in the object i have a method and that might be causing the problem but i need that method to genereate object dynamically.

```
var appointmentsPart = {  
    "id":"appointments",
    "integrationId":"1258514282"
}


var appointments = new objectPart('appointments', '1258514282');

appointments.addPart(appointmentsPart);

console.log(appointments); //this shows the correct object

function objectPart(id, integrationId){
    this.id  = id;
    this.integrationId = integrationId;
    this.part = new Array();
    this.addPart = function(obj){
        this.part.push(obj);
    }
}
```

When i make console.log() everythings is shows like i want but the problem is when i want to post this object to a php file using $.post()

```
$.post('/api.php', {api: appointments}, function(){
    console.log('test')
});
```

I get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnw586h4/4/) to help you understand my problem.

Comment: jsfiddle is empty

Comment: @AlivetoDie i updated it check it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a scoping issue here;

```
this.part = new Array();
this.addPart = function(obj){
    this.part.push(obj);
}
```

Your use of `function(obj)` creates its own scope, with its own `this` variable. So, `this.part` isn't the same one set in `this.part = new Array();`

To solve, us an *[arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)* function;

```
this.part = new Array();
this.addPart = (obj) => {
    this.part.push(obj);
}
```

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target.

Here's a forked version of you [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmxgw258/) to show you it working.

Comment: correct and detailed explanation.+1. up-voted others too

Answer (score 3):

In your `this.part.push` `this` shows not to `objectPart` function, but to `addPart` function. Miss-use of `this`; save `this` to variable to use it inside other function.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that `this` is referring to nothing. Change your code to this to get array push to work.

```
function objectPart(id, integrationId){
    this.id  = id;
    this.integrationId = integrationId;
    this.part = new Array();
    var arr = this.part;
    this.addPart = function(obj){
        arr.push(obj);
    }
}
```